# Is custom behaviour possible when asynchronously uploading?

Tags: php, ajax, uploads, plupload

I'm using Plupload and making use of wp-admin/async-upload.php to allow my website's users to upload images from the front-end asynchronously. The default behaviour of that particular script is for files to be uploaded to the media library as posts (of post_type attachment). Users may upload as many files as they like (each file upload creates a new post).

My aim is to allow users to continue to upload in this way but instead of creating a new post on each upload, I'd like the previously uploaded file to be *replaced*. Hence, users will have at most 1 post each in the system.

I don't see anything in wp-admin/async-upload.php that will allow me to hook in and add this custom behaviour.

**My question**

Is there a way to modify the default behaviour of asynchronous uploads? Or will I need to write my own async-upload.php script?

Comment: Looking through the async-uploads file it calls a function wp_ajax_upload_attachment(), this function checks to see if the post ID has been passed ( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ).

It looks like if you were to add the post_id of the previous attachment you want to edit/replace, you may be able to modify that attachment rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks Matt.. you could be on to something there! I'll check it out...

Comment: I'm 98.76% sure Plupload will let me pass the post ID via multipart_params so this looks like it could be do-able. I'll report back..

Comment: Ah, I don't think this is possible. Drilling down, the post ID is passed to `media_handle_upload()` which uses it as the `post_parent`

Comment: Bummer, I think you will have to go custom here then. You could fish around for some filters in the attachment creation process so maybe you don't have to rewrite everything. It looks like things eventually end up at wp_insert_post() in post.php, which has a couple filters you could investigate like wp_insert_attachment_data

Comment: Thanks again for the ideas, I'll have a dig around to see if anything is available.